# How to transfer Whatsapp backup from Android to iPhone using Ubuntu?

Tags: android, phone, iphone, apple, whatsapp

I need to transfer my whatsapp backup from Android phone into an iPhone.

Based on the Whatsapp official FAQ there's no easy way to do it.
The only way I found googling involves paying an application that runs on Windows or Mac which does the job.

I would like to know if any of you found out a way to do that using Ubuntu, as my laptop runs Ubuntu.

Currently my Whatsapp backup data sits on Google Drive and I can access WA files on the Android phone, however I read that Apple encrypts the messages in a different way compared to Android therefore it seems not a good idea to directly transfer such files to the iPhone.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: I do not see any Ubuntu question here.

Comment: Here it is "I would like to know if any of you found out a way to do that using Ubuntu, as my laptop runs Ubuntu."